# Linq-to-SQL statement issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am basically looking to bind a search query to a gridview which is nice, but this must be done by a users input query (sort of like a search function). I can get single values and rows returned, but how would I get it to search all columns in my database for the inputted values and return it?

My code so far is:

```
Void SearchFunction()
{
  TiamoDataContext context = new TiamoDataContext();

  var search from p in context.UserProfiles
      where p.DanceType == UserSearchString
      select p;

  UserSearchGrid.DataSource = search;
  UserSearchGrid.DataBind();
}
```

I tried p.equals but am pretty sure thats not the way to go about it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "all columns?"  Are you asking how to search for a string in every column of every table in the database?  Every column of a single table?  Or are you really just trying to search one column as the current query seems to suggest?

Comment: ahh my apologies for being unclear yes, every column in a single table would be correct... whats wrong with it currently is that its not checking all columns in the single table just DanceType column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to search every column in the table, then you have to tell it to search every column in the table.

```
var search =
    from p in context.UserProfiles
    where 
        p.DanceType == UserSearchString ||
        p.Foo == UserSearchString ||
        p.Bar == UserSearchString
    select p;
```

That's all there is to it.  There's no magic operator that will do it automatically (there can't be - some columns might not even be strings).

Keep in mind that this will likely be very slow, as the query optimizer won't be able to pick a single index that can handle this entire query.

As an aside, this "search" only tests for pure equality.  You might want to use `StartsWith` or `Contains` for a prefix or substring search, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your query sytax is a little off. It should look like:

```
var search = from p in context.UserProfiles
             where p.DanceType == UserSearchString
             select p;
```

Since you're trying to query multiple columns, you're going to have to chain the names of the columns you're looking at with `or`'s:

```
var search = from p in context.UserProfiles
             where p.DanceType == UserSearchString ||
                 p.Name == UserSearchString ||
                 p.SomeOtherStringColumn == UserSearchString
             select p;
```

Or if you want to use the Lambda syntax:

```
var search = context.UserProfiles.Where(p => p.DanceType == UserSearchString ||
                 p.Name == UserSearchString ||
                 p.SomeOtherStringColumn == UserSearchString);
```

Keep in mind that using either of these methods implies that `p.DanceType` is a `string` type.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get search all columns in a single table and was wondering how to go about this sorry that wasnt very clear :).

Comment: p.column.ToString() is what I will use to fix the string type nothing complex is stored so its not an issue.... thank you for the or I wasnt sure if that was legal syntax :)